# Can I take control of a user's Google Cloud Print printer?

Tags: google-cloud-print

We've written an application to replace a third party tool to download and print jobs through Google Cloud Print. For new customers this will work well. We create the printer in the cloud and download jobs. It works. Customers up and running with the third party tool are using a printer created with that tool. I thought I'd be able to access that printer's jobs by getting the user to go through oauth authentication to give our application the permission to manage the user's printers. However, having done this and all seeming to work when I fetch jobs from that printer the response is that there are no jobs. But there is a job. Is this behaviour to be expected. Is there any way around this? We'd just like to avoid our customers having to create new printers.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little unclear; feel free to edit your question and I'll edit this answer.

Being able to manage jobs is not the same as being able to download jobs. Each printer belongs to a user, and each has a robot account. Only those two accounts (I believe) can download the job ticket and payload.

After a job is marked as completed (through the /control API), the payload is deleted.

A third user account that can manage jobs is allowed to view information about the job, as well as cancel/delete the job, but can't (I believe) download the job payload.